Can I use a simpler loss function (e.g. direct likelihood loss) in Diffusion models?
When train a diffusion model, there are options of defining the loss function. The common ones include defining the loss functions in terms of mean or noise of a Gaussian distribution. But it always starts from the maximizing the likelihood of predicting x0 to be or close to the actual x0. Then it takes math derivations to express the loss in terms of mean or noise.
My question is that can we just use the (negative) likelihood directly as loss? I.e. at a training step, we know Xt and try to predict Xt-1, then for each pixel (i, j) if the predicted Xt-1(i,j) != actual Xt-1(i,j) then that contributes to the loss. Is what I described just slow to train/converge or is it incorrect?
Thank you!
